# ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/kobi.ktk/Desktop/uniexpo/node_modules/@expo/vector-icons/fonts' Failed building JavaScript bundle

Tags: javascript, react-native, sdk, expo, react-native-vector-icons

When I try to upgrade expo SDK version 30 -> 33 I got this error,
I tried several methods, but couldn't

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is in your component rkCalendarWeek.component.js line 52 ?

Comment: i don't have that kind of component @AnisD

Comment: npm install  --save @expo/vector-icons

Comment: i tried that too , no use @hongdevelop

Comment: same here, I tried deleting /node_modules folder and use npm install or yarn install again but still did not work, anybody knows how to solve this?